# How to implement PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, pear, ubuntu-13.10

I am trying to work with [Visual PHPUnit](https://github.com/NSinopoli/VisualPHPUnit).

When I am using `phpunit` command its running nicely. No error occurs and my tests running successfully. Output of `phpunit --version` is as follows:

`PHPUnit 4.0.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.`

I installed phpunit using PEAR. Output of `which pear` is as follows:

`/usr/bin/pear`

On Line #9 of `app/config/bootstrap.php` of Visual PHPUnit, I set `/usr/bin/pear` as `pear_path`.

It shows the following errors when I try to run VPU from browser...

**`Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path_to_vpu/app/config/bootstrap.php on line 83`**

**`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/bin/pear:/path_to_vpu:/usr/share/php') in /path_to_vpu/app/config/bootstrap.php on line 83`**

Output of `which php` is as follows:

`/usr/bin/php`

My Server is `Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy`. Output of `php -v` is as follows:

`PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.2 (cli) ....`

Output of `pear list -c phpunit` is as follows:

```
INSTALLED PACKAGES, CHANNEL PEAR.PHPUNIT.DE:  
============================================  
PACKAGE                       VERSION STATE  
DbUnit                        1.3.1   stable  
File_Iterator                 1.3.4   stable  
PHPUnit                       4.0.14  stable  
PHPUnit_Selenium              1.3.3   stable  
PHPUnit_Story                 1.0.2   stable  
PHPUnit_TicketListener_GitHub 1.0.0   stable  
PHP_CodeCoverage              1.2.17  stable  
PHP_Invoker                   1.1.3   stable  
PHP_Timer                     1.0.5   stable  
PHP_TokenStream               1.2.2   stable  
Text_Template                 1.2.0   stable
```

My question is, why I can't include `PHPUnit/Autoload.php`?

### Edit

My php.ini files (both cli and web) has the following:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear"
```

Comment: Does the file exist in `/usr/bin/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php`? In any case, I recommend using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to install dependencies.

Comment: /usr/bin/pear is a file here...

Comment: Then your `include_path` is configured incorrectly. It should only contain directories, not files

Comment: I can't figure out how to resolve this... could you please give some light on it?

Comment: Go to your *php.ini* file and search for "include_path" and adjust it.

Comment: @StefanoKowalke It might be in the bootstrap.php code as well as some samples I have seen in the past have the bootstrap calculate and modify the include path.

Answer (score 0):

Your include path is probably not setup correctly.

Follow the instructions in the [PEAR manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php), section "Verifying the include path".

Comment: both web php and cli php shows me bool(true) according to the manual... But still PHPUnit is not included... Please help me... Again phpunit is working fine from command prompt but web interface is not working...

Answer (score 0):

This is what happened to me after PHPUnit upgrade with PEAR. Before upgrade, VPU was working. Also I could not downgrade it via PEAR. After some tweaking, it worked again.

I installed PHPUnit under VPU web directory using composer. Place this composer.json file in VPU web directory.

```
composer.json
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*"
    }
}
```

and run composer install. After this, a small change in app/config/bootstrap.php file is needed;

```
//require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
//require_once 'PHPUnit/Util/Log/JSON.php';

// this should be absolute path
require_once '/var/www/.... vpu web path ..../vendor/autoload.php';
```

and it will work.